# Не работает jQuery Click по картинке

Tags: jquery

Первый клик работает, на второй не хочет...
В чем может быть проблемма?

```js
$('.hidden').on('click', function() {
  $('#contact_us').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#contact_us').addClass('open');
});
$('#close_button_img').on('click', function() {
  $('#contact_us').removeClass('open');
  $('#contact_us').addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 8%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: central;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  width: 34px;
  height: 140px;
  max-width: 34px;
  max-height: 140px;
  background: #FBC449;
  border: 1px solid #FFDD8F;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0 2px 0 #B8A3AF;
  box-shadow: -2px 0 2px 0 #B8A3AF;
}

.hidden>div {
  display: none;
}

.open {
  display: normal;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 13%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: central;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #FFDD8F;
  border: 1px solid #FBC449;
}

#contact_us_body input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #FBC449;
  border: 1px solid #FFDD8F;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  margin: 12px 24px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0 2px 0 #B8A3AF;
  box-shadow: -2px 0 2px 0 #B8A3AF;
  transition: 1s;
}

#contact_us_body input:hover {
  width: 210px;
  height: 64px;
  background: #FFDD8F;
  border: 2px solid #FBC449;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  margin: 8px 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0 4px 0 #B8A3AF;
  box-shadow: -2px 0 4px 0 #B8A3AF;
  transition: 1s;
}

#contact_us_up {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FBC449;
}

#close_button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: right;
  margin: -40px -30px;
  transition: 1s;
  background: #FBC449;
  border: 1px solid #FBC449;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#close_button:hover {
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

#close_button img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Contact US-->
<div id="contact_us" class="hidden">
  Contacteaza-ne
  <div id="contact_us_body">
    <div id="contact_us_up">
      <div id="close_button" class="close_button"><img src="style/img/plus.png" id="close_button_img" /></div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Numele:" alt="Numele:" title="Numele:" />
      <input type="number" placeholder="GSM:" alt="GSM:" title="GSM:" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Domeniu:" alt="Domeniu:" title="Domeniu:" />
      <input type="button" value="Astept un Sunet" alt="Astept un Sunet" title="Astept un Sunet" id="send_recall" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="contact_us_down"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!--Contact US-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Поправочка, проблема скорее всего в том, что первый слушатель реагирует на нажатие на родительский элемент у которого класс `hidden`, а второй слушатель на элемент, вложенный в него, таким образом, кликая на вложенный элемент срабатывают сразу 2 события, и в итоге класс `hidden` удаляется и тут же снова добавляется и кажется что ничего не происходит.

Я бы советовал скрывать не родительский элемент, а вместо этого внутри `contact_us` добавить кнопку и блок с контентом которому и будет добавляться класс `hidden`.

Либо кнопку сделать вовсе за пределами блока `contact_us`.

И, как правильно заметили в ответе ниже, нужно использовать делегирование:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(e) {
  <!--Ваш код-->
});
```

Это не относится напрямую к вашей проблеме, просто хорошая практика, такая привычка предотвратит кучу проблем в будущем.

Comment: ПО этому второй раз событие вешаю на #close_button_img, а не на hidden

Answer (score 4):

Объяснение в ответе выше неправильное. Событие навешивается на элемент (или элементы), который ищется по классу `hidden`. Таким образом, важно наличие этого класса в момент вызова `$('.hidden').on('click', ...`. В дальнейшем, класс у элемента (или элементов) можно удалить, обработчик события от этого не отсоединится.

Чтобы обработчик вызывался для элементов, у которых есть класс `hidden` в момент клика, независимо от того, наличествует ли этот класс в момент назначения обработчика (и вообще, существует ли в тот момент сам элемент), используйте делегирование:

```
$(document).on("click", ".hidden", function(e) {
  ...
});
```

Но в Вашем случае достаточно просто:

```
$('.hidden').on('click', function() {
  $('#contact_us').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#contact_us').addClass('open');
});

$('#close_button_img').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // !!!
  $('#contact_us').removeClass('open');
  $('#contact_us').addClass('hidden');
});
```

Что происходит у Вас - без `e.stopPropagation();`:

При клике по `close_button_img` сначала выполняется обработчик `$('#close_button_img').on('click',` - пока что все хорошо, элемент прячется, но потом событие "всплывает" до родительского элемента `<div id="contact_us" class="hidden">`, у которого тоже есть обработчик - элемент показывается опять, и Bы даже не успеваете заметить, что его выключили/включили.

Comment: Первый вызов при клике на .hidden

      $('.hidden').on('click', function(){
        $('#contact_us').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#contact_us').addClass('open');
    });





Второй раз уже на #close_button_img

    $('#close_button_img').on('click', function(){
        $('#contact_us').removeClass('open');
        $('#contact_us').addClass('hidden');
    });